# Using shared element transitions from a non-activity class to an activity class

Tags: android, android-studio, activity-transition

I have a non-activty class (precisely a RecyclerView Adapter holding cardviews), I am trying to use "authentic motion" transition from the cardview to the final activity using a shared image element. I easily implemented it between two activity classes but from a non-activity class to activity class, I am unable to do so?

Here's my code (RecyclerViewAdapter.java):

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

```
public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;
    TextView myid;
    front ft = new front();

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        myid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.IDTAG);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        cv.setUseCompatPadding(true);
        cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                final String cardid = myid.getText().toString().trim();
                Intent callIntent = new Intent("io.brushed.databasecardview.VIEWDATAINSIDE");
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                callIntent.putExtra("THEID",cardid);
                String transitionName = "oktrans";
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                        personPhoto,   // The view which starts the transition
                        transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
                );
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, callIntent, options.toBundle());

            }
        });



    }
}

List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
    this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.myid.setText(persons.get(i).id);
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return persons.size();
}

}
```

Its not able to resolve "this" keyword, what am I supposed to replace it with as the RecyclerView adapter is a non-activity class?

Comment: You need to pass your click event from `RecyclerViewAdapter` to your `RecyclerView` container `Activity`. After that, you can start another `Activity` from there using this code.

Comment: I am total newbie, I don't know how to pass click events. I have set onClickListener on my cardview, what exactly am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the context of your activity class to your non-activty class (precisely a RecyclerView Adapter holding cardviews)

e.g.

```
RecyclerViewAdapter1(Context context...)
```

Then use that context for this purpose:

```
String transitionName = "oktrans";
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
personPhoto,transitionName);
ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, callIntent, options.toBundle());
```

Edit:

Based on your new edit.

Pass Activity as an argument.

```
PersonalViewHolder(View view, Activity activity) {
...
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, ...);
}

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


CardView cv;
TextView personName;
TextView personAge;
ImageView personPhoto;
TextView myid;
front ft = new front();

PersonViewHolder(View itemView, final Context context) {
    super(itemView);
    personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
    personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
    personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
    myid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.IDTAG);
    cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
    cv.setUseCompatPadding(true);
    cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            final String cardid = myid.getText().toString().trim();
            Intent callIntent = new Intent("io.brushed.databasecardview.VIEWDATAINSIDE");
            callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            callIntent.putExtra("THEID",cardid);
            String transitionName = "oktrans";
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(context,
                    personPhoto,   // The view which starts the transition
                    transitionName    // The transitionName of the view we’re transitioning to
            );
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, callIntent, options.toBundle());

        }
    });



}
```

}

```
List<Person> persons;

RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
this.persons = persons;
}

@Override
 public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
 }

 @Override
 public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)   {
   View v =    LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,   viewGroup, false);
   PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v, viewGroup.getContext());
  return pvh;
 }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i)    {
personViewHolder.myid.setText(persons.get(i).id);
personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return persons.size();
}

}
```

Comment: I updated my code, can you kindly tell me exactly what am I supposed to do.

Comment: are you using onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) method in your code

Comment: I updated my full RecyclerView Adapter code, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to use `this` because you are inside a block which is holding the reference to it.

Also, if you see the proper implementation of startActivity() method.

It needs the following arguments:

```
startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, Bundle options)
```

Pass your activity like `ActivityName.this` or `getActivity()` if in Fragment

Edit:

Based on your new edit.

Pass Activity as an argument.

```
PersonalViewHolder(View view, Activity activity) {
...
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, ...);
}
```

Comment: I updated my code, kindly have a look. As you can see I am trying to start the intent within PersonViewHolder class of my RecyclerView adpater class (which itself is a non-activity). I am a total newbie, can you guide me what exactly am I supposed to do?

Comment: Just put getActivity() instead of this. Also, initialize views on top, not at the end.

Comment: I dont think your ViewHolder class should be inside Adapter class.

Comment: How can I pass activity as argument?

Comment: You can pass the activity wherever you are calling PersonalViewHolder instance.

Comment: `@Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);

        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v,ACTIVITY);
        return pvh;
    }`

What should I write instead of ACTIVITY?